# Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority while Third Party Apps are Disabled

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

In Google Apps domains: Is it possible to grant domain-wide delegation of authority to third-party apps while the  "Allow users to install Google Drive Apps" setting  in the Admin Console is disabled.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOirA.png)

To be specific: I am trying to find out if there is a workaround the Admin Console Settings. The enterprise social network already has the capability to work with Google Drive but none of my files show up because of the App settings in the Admin Console.

Comment: This question should be on [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps that are published in the "Google Apps Marketplace" (https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace) can be installed by a domain administrator for all users in a domain. This will bypass the setting you mentioned.